# How do I swap an element of a C++ stack

Tags: c++, stack

I have this task to do. Basically, I have to create a dynamic stack, then I have to choose an element and swap it with a new one which I inserted. The other elements remain the same and I have to display the new data. I've come to a dead end.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct elem
{
    int key;
    elem* next;
} *start = NULL, *p;

void push(int n);
int pop(int &n);

int main()
{
    int num, counter = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Input integers(!=0): ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num > 0 || num < 0)
        {
            push(num);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    while (num != 0);
    cout << "\nStack: ";
    while (pop(num))
        cout << num << "\t";
    cout << "\n";

    int element, newValue;
    cout << "Input element number: ";
    cin >> element;
    cout << "New value of element: ";
    cin >> newValue;
```

here I struggle doing the swap

```
    return 0;
}

void push(int n)
{
    p = start;
    start = new elem;
    start->key = n;
    start->next = p;
}

int pop(int &n)
{
    if (start)
    {
        n = start->key;
        p = start;
        start = start->next;
        delete p;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pop first, pop second, push first, push second.

Comment: Call your stack S. Create a temporary stack T. Pop (n - 1) elements from S, push them onto T. Pop the unwanted element from S. Push the new element to S. Pop the elements from T, push them onto S.

Comment: You need two stacks. Pass the relevant stack to your functions instead of using a global one.

Answer (score 0):

How do you swap a chosen one from a stack of (dinner) plates with the top one?

you pick the topmost, put it aside, then pick all the ones you don't want and put them on a new stack until you reach the chosen one. Pick it, exchange it with the original topmost one, put the chosen one aside.

Then re-stack, one by one, the plates from the new stack to the old one. Lastly, put the one you put aside on top.

Answer (score 0):

Going through an intermediary stack like @Bathsheba suggested is the most straight forward solution here.
You can also save some execution time by simply modifying the "next" var of the previous
element to the element you're going the change.

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct elem
{
    int key; 
    elem* next;
} 
*start = NULL, *p,*previous,*curr,*temp;

void push(int n);
int pop(int &n);

int main() {
    int num, counter = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Input integers(!=0): ";
        cin >> num;
        if (num > 0 || num < 0) {
            push(num);
            counter++;
        }
    } 
    while (num != 0);
    /*    cout << "\nStack: ";
    while (pop(num))
        cout << num << "\t";
    cout << "\n";
    */
    int element, newValue;
    cout << "Input element number: ";
    cin >> element;
    cout << "New value of element: ";
    cin >> newValue; 
    curr = start ;
    previous = NULL; 
    while(curr->next)
    {
        
        if(curr->key == element){
            if(previous) {
                temp = new elem;
                temp->key = newValue;
                temp->next = curr->next ;
                previous->next = temp ;
                break;
            }
            else {
                temp = new elem;
                temp->key = newValue;
                temp->next = curr->next ;
                start = temp ;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            previous = curr ;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
         
    }
    while (pop(num))
        cout << num << "\t";
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}

void push(int n) {
    p = start;
    start = new elem;
    start->key = n;
    start->next = p;
}

int pop(int &n) {
    if (start) {
        n = start->key;
        p = start;
        start = start->next;
        delete p;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tested it but it does not swap the element or maybe I am understanding wrong some things.

Comment: Really ? I ran through a couple of tests and it gave the correct stack.Did you test out this code ?

Comment: yes, I can provide screenshots. Your solution does show the stack in the end and does not swap the selected element.  For example I selected to swap the 4th element and it didn't swap.